# Questions related to JavaScript object literal and google map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

This code is not working as expected. I am trying to use the Google Geolocation API to figure out my current location. However, when I try to log the result for the google.maps.LatLng object, I got (0,0) as the latitude and longitude coordinates.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var func = {
                lat:0,
                long:0,
                success:function(pos) {
                  var crd = pos.coords;
                  this.lat = crd.latitude;
                  this.long = crd.longitude;
                },

                error:function(err) {
                  console.log('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
                },

                init:function(){
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.success, this.error);
                }

            };

            func.init();

            $('button').on('click',function(){
                var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(func.lat, func.long);

                alert(loc);
            });
        });
```

However, the code underneath works. All I did was changing "this" keyword to the object's name. It shouldn't make a difference.

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            var func = {
                lat:0,
                long:0,
                success:function(pos) {
                  var crd = pos.coords;
                  func.lat = crd.latitude;
                  func.long = crd.longitude;
                },

                error:function(err) {
                  console.log('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
                },

                init:function(){
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(func.success, func.error);
                }

            };

            func.init();

            $('button').on('click',function(){
                var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(func.lat, func.long);

                alert(loc);
            });
        });
```

I am not sure why the code snippet on the top produces incorrect output? I am not too familiar with Objected Oriented JavaScript. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me understand what is going on.

Comment: You've stated "Questions" in the title but your post does not include a question statement or a clearly defined problem statement.

Comment: My question is why the code snippet on the top produces incorrect output? I was thinking maybe I used JavaScript Object literal incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, but readers should be able to understand what the question is by reading a question statement in your post. Please [edit] your question to clarify the intent of your question. Let us know what the expected result should be and what the result currently is. Believe it or not, phrasing is a big part of what makes a question good or bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, when you call:

```
getCurrentPosition(this.success, this.error);
```

You are merely passing the `success` and `error` functions into `getCurrentPosition`. Even though you reference them here via `this`, that is not carried through to the point where the functions are actually called. It only passes the function references themselves, not the `this` value that you were using here.

Another way to understand the problem: the value of `this` inside a function is determined *at the time the function is called*. When you write `foo.bar()` you are calling the `bar()` function with `foo` as the `this` value inside the function. But when you write `foo.bar` without the `()`, you are only getting a reference to `bar` itself. `foo` is out of the picture after that. If you pass `foo.bar` into another function which expects a callback, when it finally calls `bar()` there is no longer any association with `foo`.

That's why your second example works. It does not depend on `this` but uses `func` which is valid throughout the outer function.